# excel formula when i enter a date in a column it updates a another cell to display the mm-yy a year or 6months later

Tags: excel, date

Lab has to keep track of when preventative maintenance (PM) was done and when the next PM is due.  I want to enter the date PM was performed in a cell and then have another cell automatically update to a year or six months later.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have your data in A1, the formula to add 6 month to the data in B1 is

```
=EDATE(A1;6)
```

Then format the cell B1 to date
Same applyes to C1, add 12 to obtain 1 year from the date

Comment: Thanks that helps.  What you suggest for this format? We have to track each time it is PM so I have to enter a new date in a new cell each time PM is done.  Or is there a better format to track that and have PM due automaticall update once the next PM history cell is filled?  I was trying to do an find the last filled in cell in a range then use that cell as the edate.                                                                                                                                   
Next PM Due  PM History PM History PM History PM History
May-22   20-May-20 20-May-21